# Error executing task XamlCTask- Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, compiler-errors

I am stucking with this error for several days:

/Upackages/Xamarin.Forms.2.3.3.175/build/portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20/Xamarin.Forms.targets:

**Error: Error executing task XamlCTask:**

Could not find file "/Users/XXXX/obj/Debug/XXXX.dll.mdb".

Firstly, I updated the xamarin.forms, but the error was appeared again to me. Then, I clean each project and build it again, but no change has happened.

So, I am wondering what can I do? It has just shown to me since some days ago, before I could compile my project easily.

Comment: I had the exact same error, but this answer solved it;
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43584964/1775605

Comment: I have a solution for your problems: AVOID XAMARIN COMPLETELY, it's not worth it. Take it from me, I've been using it for 2 years and my app had over 50k downloads, I have enough experience to back this. It's just not worth it, if you want a nice language, use Kotlin. Xamarin is buggy, slow as hell, massive app size and overall unmaintanable. I'm going to be porting my app to Kotlin with databindings.

Comment: @Spacemonkey very true! i am also working on xamarin forms from last one year , it's very buggy and app size is definately bigger than native implementation

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but using Visual Studio for MAC.
Try doing the following:

Go to "Preferences"
Then look for .Net Runtimes.

I was using: Mono 5.*
I changed my default to Mono 4.* and I was able to build successfully.

**NOTE:** Make sure that all the packages for Xamarin.Forms are also the same version.